# .htaccess: Redirect all pages to a new domain, except certain pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a blog website with a Wordpress instalation. The blog author will now start posting for the local newspaper. Basically, I want this:

- All the articles/pages should redirect to the new blog home at the newspaper's website.
- A few articles should not redirect to the home page, but to its new URL at the newspaper's website.

So far I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect specific articles
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} article-slug-goes-here
RewriteRule .* http://www.newspaper.com/theblog/588433/article-slug-goes-here.html [R=301,L]


# Redirect all other stuff to the home
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newspaper.com/theblog/ [R=301,L]
```

The first part works, but no the other part. I should be able to add other articles to the redirect list so that they are redirected to their corresponding new URL.

Comment: You have only these 2 rules? What about default WP rules?

Comment: I removed them. They wouldn't be doing anything anyway.

Comment: If it is a WP installation then you do need WP rewrite rules

Comment: No, I don't. I'd be doing the redirects with these rules. If I place the WP redirect rules at the bottom, they would never even execute.

Comment: Ok but you wrote: `A few articles should not redirect to the home page` but I don't see any URLs for those articles you want to skip redirecting.

Comment: @anubhava At this moment there is only one (where it says `Redirect specific articles`). But I would like to have a list there. The logic is: is the requested URL in the redirect list? then redirect to its new URL. If it's not, then redirect to the new home page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect specific articles
RewriteRule ^(article1|article2|article3) http://www.newspaper.com/theblog/588433/article-slug-goes-here.html [R=301,L]

# Redirect all other stuff to the home
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newspaper.com/theblog/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That would redirect article1, article2 and article3 to the same URL. Each article has its own *new* URL. But I'll try to see if this would allow me to make a list of the articles using similar rules.

Comment: Sure you can do that. I just gave a sample to you since I didn't know all the requirements.

Comment: @anubhava could you give the same example where article1, article2 and article3 point to different target urls?

Comment: @Jan: It is not fair to modify original answer for a different requirement. Can you please post a question and I will try to answer it there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483366/htaccess-redirect-some-subpages-to-new-subpage-all-others-to-new-main-page