# .htaccess: Redirect some subpages to new subpage, all others to new main page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have searched SO for answers but have not found any matching my criteria.
I am moving a webshop to a new domain (it has 1000s of products). For the pages with some decent rankings, I want to redirect them to their new respective subpages. All other pages I want to redirect to the new main page.
I am trying to accomplish this using .htaccess

```
shopold.com/cat/product1.html to shopnew.com/category/product1
shopold.com/cat/product2.html to shopnew.com/category/product2
All other pages from shopold.com to shopnew.com
```

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?shopold\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^cat/product1\.html$ http://shopnew.com/category/product1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^cat/product2\.html$ http://shopnew.com/category/product2 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^ http://shopnew.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

In general keep known-product rules at top and keep generic catch-all rule at the bottom.

---

Here is a non-regex way of comparing `REQUEST_URI`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/cat/product1.html
RewriteRule ^ http://shopnew.com/category/product1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Unfortunately it requires use of a `RewriteCond` since pattern in `RewriteRule` does require a regex.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that this is relevant for both www and non www versions due to `(?:www\.)?` right? Thank you

Comment: Yes that's correct. `(?:www\.)?` makes starting `www.` optional.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use the link from shopold (^cat/product1\.html$) as a string only without using regex? Thank you for your help anubhava